# WPF MVVM Datagrid Cell Validation Error Behavior Issue: Why is my value being removed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

My issue is the behavior of the validation errors in the DataGrid. It validates against my model object's property and displays the correct message, but the validation disappears, along with the original value whenever I select a different row.

In the example .gif below, I remove the name (backspace), hit enter (get the validation message), then click to a different row. Whenever the selected row changes I would expect either a) the validation error to remain OR b) the original value to return, but the row stays blank and the validation error is gone until I double click the row. Once I double click, the original value returns.

[image: datagrid behavior]

I would prefer the validation error to persist, but I'll take either at this point.

Here is the datagrid textblock style:

```
    <Style x:Key="datagridElemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Here is the actual DataGridTextColumn:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="NAME"
                    Width="300"
                    Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, 
                             ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource datagridElemStyle}"
                    CanUserReorder="False" />
```

This is my ViewModel wrapper object (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
public class PointVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Point DataContext { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return DataContext.Name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != DataContext.Name)
            {
                DataContext.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally, here is my Model (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
public abstract class Point
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            string trimmedVal = value.Trim();
            #region Validation
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmedVal))
                throw new Exception("Name cannot be empty.");

            if (Regex.IsMatch(trimmedVal, @"[^A-Za-z0-9\-_ ]$"))
                throw new Exception("Invalid character in name.");

            if (trimmedVal.Length > 64)
               throw new Exception("Name is too long.");

            if ((from p in PointList
                 where p.Name.Equals(trimmedVal, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                 select p).Count() > 0)
                throw new Exception("Name is already used.");
            #endregion
            _name = trimmedVal;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid validations can be super annoying. When a `DataGridTextColumn` begins editing, the actual value of the binding is restored, which is why you see a revert when you enter edit mode.

You basically need to stop that call by handling the `BeginningEdit` event for the DataGrid.

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" BeginningEdit="dg_BeginningEdit">
```

Code-Behind

```
   private void dg_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
   {
       e.EditingEventArgs.Handled = true;
   }
```

FYI: Your binding updates on `LostFocus`. This solution may not work well if you update on `PropertyChanged` in the future as it changes the order of operation.

Comment: This appears to have no effect, at least in regards to the behavior I posted above.

Comment: @Chris That’s strange as I replicated your shown behavior and fixed it with this. I wonder if something else triggering the revert. What .NET framework are you using?

Comment: Playing around with it some more, it feels like the error is removed whenever the IsSelected property is toggled on that row. It stays invalid until I select it again. Once I select it, the validation error clears, but the row is not "refreshed" so it keeps displaying an empty field.